# Spring Boot Can't Connect To MySQL,"Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required"

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

I have created a Spring Boot + MyBatis backend project and attempted to connect it to my MySQL database, but I have been unable to establish a successful connection. Every time I run the project, I encounter the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-01T15:50:26.598+08:00 ERROR 20088 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cityMapper' defined in file [D:\BLER\target\classes\fun\aaronwu\bler\mapper\CityMapper.class]: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at fun.aaronwu.bler.BlerApplication.main(BlerApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(SqlSessionDaoSupport.java:122) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:73) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have searched for solutions to similar issues on the internet, and I have made corrections to the possible error aspects as suggested. However, I still cannot run the project successfully.

Below is the content of the project that may be relevant to this error. I hope someone can help me identify the reason for the runtime error.

1.This is the overall structure of the project. Currently, I have only implemented the CityMapper, but even with just this one Mapper, I consistently encounter errors：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9665b.png)

2.This is the content of the application.properties file. I can ensure that the database name and password are correct.

```
server.port=8081
server.servlet.context-path=/BLER-BackEnd

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aaron_recruitment_website?serverTimezone=GMT%2B8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=517pacifikal

mybatis.mapper-locations=fun.aaronwu.bler.mapper/*.xml
```

3.This is a image showing my database in navicat.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwfp4.png)

4.This is the code in CityMapper.java:

```
package fun.aaronwu.bler.mapper;

import fun.aaronwu.bler.entity.City;
import fun.aaronwu.bler.entity.Company;
import fun.aaronwu.bler.entity.Job;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * 城市映射接口，定义对City表的操作
 *
 * @author AaronWu
 */

@Mapper
public interface CityMapper {

    /**
     * 插入
     * @param c 城市对象
     */
    //void insert(City c);

    /**
     * 更新
     * @param c 城市对象
     */
    //void update(City c);

    /**
     * 删除
     * @param c 城市对象
     */
    //void delete(City c);

    /**
     * 根据ID得到城市
     * @param cId 城市ID
     * @return 城市对象
     */
    //City getOneById(UUID cId);

    /**
     * 根据名称得到城市
     * @param cName 城市名称
     * @return 城市对象
     */
    //City getOneByName(String cName);

    /**
     * 获取全部城市
     * @return 城市列表
     */
    //List<City> getAllCities();

    /**
     * 动态获取企业或者岗位所在的城市
     * @param company 企业对象
     * @param job 岗位对象
     * @return 城市列表
     */
    //List<City> getCityDynamically(@Param("company")Company company, @Param("job")Job job);
}
```

5.This is the code in CityMapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="fun.aaronwu.bler.mapper.CityMapper">

</mapper>
```

6.This is the code in BlerApplication:

```
package fun.aaronwu.bler;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("fun.aaronwu.bler.mapper")
@EnableCaching
public class BlerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

7.This is the code in pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.aaronwu</groupId>
    <artifactId>BLER</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BLER</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--1. Web启动依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--2. thymeleaf启动依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--3. devtools依赖：热部署-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--4. mybatis-spring启动依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--5. druid启动依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--6. mysql驱动依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--7. lombok依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--8. commons-fileupload依赖： 添加该依赖会添加commons-fileupload依赖和commons-io依赖 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--9. 测试启动更依赖-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.53</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I wish someone can help me solve this problem, make me connect to the database successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the dependency of hibernate:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you have two options the frist is to use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This will autoconfigure the datasource using `spring.datasource` properties

The second option is to manually configure the beans for datasource and sqlFactory removing the depenecy of `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:file:C:/temp/test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

you can inject in the configuration the properties needed to configure the datasource